# Notation for calculating $p(v)$ marginalising over $h$ in an Restricted Boltzmann Machine

Tags: notation, marginal-distribution, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am working through equation 22 in [Introduction to Boltzmann Machines](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/1ercuat2018/probabilidades_y_estadistica_C/5a89b5075af5cbef5becaf419457cdd77cc9.pdf)

I am a little confused with the notation, in particular in the line:

[image]

As I understand it, we want the probability of a specific state of the visible nodes, $v = \{v_1, v_2, ... v_m\}$ where $v_j \in \{0, 1\}$. We are marginalising over all possible states of the hidden nodes, $H$, where $h \in H$ and $h = \{h_1, h_2, ..., h_n\}, h_i \in \{0, 1\}$.

For me, this then makes sense if in the above notation, the sum $\sum_{h_n}$ over $h_n$ (i.e., an single hidden node) means to sum over every possible state of $h_n$, i.e. $h_n = 1$ and $h_n = 0$. Is this correct? And, this is equivalent to $\sum_h e^{-E(v, h)}$ because we are summing the probability of $v$ over every possible arrangement of $h$ (of which there are $2^{|h|}$ combinations)?

Comment: Thanks to kind personal response from the lead author following an enquiring email, I can confirm the above interpretation is correct.